# ExcelDna - Excel can't access function in base class

Tags: excel-dna

When Excel tries to call a method in a abstract base class i get a Run-Time error

"Cannot run Marco 'MarcoName'. The macro may not be available"

I can run code from the super class.

The code is similar to this

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public static bool MyMethod(string path)
    {
         if(Valid(path))
             {return true;}
         return false;
    }
}
```

This code is in a separate assembly imported via a nuget package

The calling code is similar to the below

```
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public static bool MyOtherMethod()
    {
         return true;
    }
}
```

Marking the methods with the "[ExcelFunction]" attribute has no effect.

I am loading the xll file like so,

```
Application.RegisterXLL (path)
```

I call the method  like so,

```
Application.Run("MyMethod", path)
```

Answer (score 1):

Only code in assemblies that are included in the `<ExternalLibrary ... />` list in the .dna file are scanned for functions to register. Maybe your external assembly is not mentioned there.

Also, abstract types were not always considered. It looks like this changed at some point, if I look at the code that scans the assemblies here: https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/blob/57c2d0a499a044f6cd1c4ae2c9fbf5b084159dea/Source/ExcelDna.Integration/AssemblyLoader.cs#L93
So it might depend on your Excel-DNA version too.

Easiest might be to have a class with all the functions you want to export, where you can add the Excel-specific attributes (`<ExcelFunction .../>`) and just forward the calls internally.